# Check object null or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to check if User exists or not in the database, and i take a User object and check if it is null or not.But the problem is in my code if user doen't exist in our database it returns following exception,

> > Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I know this error happen when there is no such a user in our database.So.. i wanted to know if this user object( i want to return null or not) null or not.

My Part of Code

```
  if(newsManager.GetUserUsingEmail(User.Email).Email != null) //If user doesn't exists this come the above mentioned exception
    {
        //User Exists
    }
    else
    {
       //User Doesn't exists
    }
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: should be `newsManager.GetUserUsingEmail(User.Email) != null`

Comment: Do we really need four answers to this all saying essentially the same thing?

Comment: @MickyDuncan My answer was first, but I think at least one of the others must have been started before mine was posted.

Answer (score 2):

The null reference exception is probably due to you trying to access the `Email` property on the user returned from the `GetUserUsingEmail` method. You should test if the returned value is null first and only then try accessing properties on it.

```
var user = newsManager.GetUserUsingEmail(User.Email);
if (user != null)
{
     // user exists
}
else
{
    // user does not exist
}
```

Comment: I think this has the best code structure of the answers presented where the statement `GetUserUsingEmail()` is not repeated.

Answer (score 0):

if `newsManager.GetUserUsingEmail(User.Email)` returns `null`, then you will agree that attempting to invoke `.Email` should give you the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error, right?

As suggested in the comments, if your condition is truly just checking to see if the user exists or not, then simply do this:

```
if(newsManager.GetUserUsingEmail(User.Email) != null) //If user doesn't exists this come the above mentioned exception
{
    //User Exists
}
else
{
    //User Doesn't exists
}
```

If, as your code suggests, your intent is really to enter the `if` block only if you have a valid `Email` value for a valid user, then you can do that like this instead:

```
var user = newsManager.GetUserUsingEmail(User.Email);
if(user != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Email))
{
    //User Exists and has a valid email
}
else
{
    //User Doesn't exists or doesn't have a valid email.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get property from null. Check object != null instead:

```
if(newsManager.GetUserUsingEmail(User.Email) != null) //If user doesn't exists this come the above mentioned exception
    {
        //User Exists
    }
    else
    {
       //User Doesn't exists
    }
```

In C# 6.0 you can use Safe Navigation Operator (?.):

```
 if(newsManager.GetUserUsingEmail(User.Email)?.Email != null) //If user doesn't exists this come the above mentioned exception
    {
        //User Exists
    }
    else
    {
       //User Doesn't exists
    }
```